# Eclipse-PDT - is there a way to remove false syntax error annotation in vertical ruler

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

sometimes, the false syntax error annotation stays in vertical bar in Eclipse. After fixing the error and saving the file, the annotation still stays displayed. Is there any way to remove such annotation or clean all the annotations?

[image: False Syntax Error]

Thank you.

Comment: If the markers aren't deleted via _Project > Clean.._, you can delete markers in the _Problems_ view. Is this (markers are not removed by mistake) a problem of the latest version of Eclipse PDT (Eclipse Oxygen.1) or do you use an older version?

Comment: I use Version: Oxygen Release (4.7.0)
Build id: 20170620-1800

Comment: Unfortunately, the false syntax error is not listed in Problems view and Clean command does not clean the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [seems to be a known problem](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=515526) of Eclipse PDT 5.0 which has **already been fixed in Eclipse PDT 5.1, alias Oxygen.1** (see [list of bugs fixed in PDT 5.1](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?list_id=16397460&product=PDT&query_format=advanced&target_milestone=5.1)):

1. ***Help > Check for Updates***
2. Follow the instructions of the dialog